# Getting mapping error while loading datatable from sqlreader

Tags: c#, sql-server

Getting error while loading datatable from sqlreader, on below line

```
empPrivDataTable.Load(sqlReader);
```

Here is the full method:

```
 private void LoadEmployeePrivilegeGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id as Id, (select Name from Room r where r.id = ap.RoomId) as Room, cast(ap.DateFrom as date) as Date,  CONVERT(varchar(15), cast(ap.DateFrom as time), 100) as TimeFrom,  CONVERT(varchar(15), cast(ap.DateTo as time), 100) as TimeTo FROM Access_Privilege ap where EmployeeId = @EmployeeId", sqlConnection);
            //SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id as Id from Access_Privilege", sqlConnection);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", empNmCmbBx.SelectedValue.ToString());
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (sqlReader.HasRows)
            {
                currPrvDtGrdView.Visible = true;
                empPrivDataTable.Load(sqlReader);
                currPrvDtGrdView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                currPrvDtGrdView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Id";
                currPrvDtGrdView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Room";
                currPrvDtGrdView.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Date";
                currPrvDtGrdView.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "TimeFrom";
                currPrvDtGrdView.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "TimeTo";
                currPrvDtGrdView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                currPrvDtGrdView.DataSource = empPrivDataTable;
            }
            sqlReader.Close();
        }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SGFinalProjectRoomAllocationSystem.ManageAccessForm.LoadEmployeePrivilegeGrid() in c:\Projects\SGFinalProjectRoomAllocationSystem\SGFinalProjectRoomAllocationSystem\ManageAccessForm.cs:line 110 at SGFinalProjectRoomAllocationSystem.ManageAccessForm.empNmCmbBx_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\SGFinalProjectRoomAllocationSystem\SGFinalProjectRoomAllocationSystem\ManageAccessForm.cs:line 221
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Have you set `empPrivDataTable` to something? That's the only variable I can see that needs to be instantiated but where I can't see that it's happening. The error message tells what line this is on. It would help if you indicated which line of code that is since we can't see the line numbers.

Comment: Damn it! Great catch. Not sure how that got missed. I had that in my earlier code but somehow missed it. Thanks!